# Populate UI Table View with array of strings

Tags: ios, uitableview

I can't find a simple, concise answer anywhere and I refuse to believe that XCode makes things as hard as other tutorials I've found out there...

Say I have the following array

`NSArray* days = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sunday",@"Monday",@Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturday",nil];`

I have a UI Table View, `table_Days`, that I would like to simply show the items from my array.  What is the proper way to go about populating my table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my full explanation, starting with a case extremely similar to yours:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_table_view_data

So suppose `days` is stored as an instance variable accessed through a property `self.days`. Then set `self` as the table view's `datasource` and use this code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (!self.days) // data not ready?
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.days count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell =
        [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = (self.days)[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You should definitely buy @matt's book if you need answers to ask basic questions like this.

Comment: I've seen similar explanations around.  This is definitely the best I've seen, however as an experienced programmer I'm still absolutely shocked it takes 3 methods to populate a table with strings.

Comment: Where do these methods live?  I see that I don't directly call them, but how does my tableview know to use them?

Comment: You implement them in whatever object you set as the tableview's datasource / delegate. see this url: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10

Comment: And while it may seem verbose with 3 methods, the pattern supports far more advanced cases than simply creating a list from an array. If you are not familiar with it you should have a look at the Delegation pattern and how Protocols are used in Objective-C.

Comment: @RhinoFeeder "as an experienced programmer I'm still absolutely shocked" See the first few paragraphs of my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_table_view_cells Yes, you might expect the data to be stored in the table (I expected that, coming from REALbasic years ago), but it turns out there's a lot more going on here than you think, and it is worth trying to wrap your head around why it's great. This is true model-view-controller architecture, plus the cells are reused (i.e. you can show 1000 rows with just a dozen table cells).

Comment: Thanks matt, I just had to add your methods, set the .h file to implement from UITableView and everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You should populate your table view using the [data source methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource). Returning the `count` of the array for the number of rows.

If you need to detect when a user taps on a cell you can use the [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) methods.

```
@interface ViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *days;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableDays;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *tableDays; // Set this up
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    tableDays.delegate = self;
    tableDays.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableDays];
    self.tableDays = tableDays;

    self.days = @[@"Sunday", @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday", @"Thursday", @"Friday", @"Saturday"];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.days count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.days[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *day = self.days[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Day tapped: %@", day);
}

@end
```

You should consider using a [`UITableViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you just want to show a table view.

Note that its better practice to use camel case for variables.